# How to convert assembly code to executable in LLVM

Tags: compilation, llvm, cross-compiling

I have converted c program into assembly code using following commands in LLVM :

```
clang -emit-llvm matrix.c -c -o matrix.bc
llc -march=alpha matrix.bc -o matrix.s
```

Now how to convert matrix.s assembly file into executable file of alpha.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`clang` can also be used

```
clang matrix.s -L [additional library locations] -mllvm -Wall -g -L. -Wl,-pie -I. -I[additional include locations] -o [executable output]
```

Adjust the flags as your needs dictate.

**EDIT**

Without the need for other includes or libraries just call:

```
clang matrix.s -mllvm -Wall -g -Wl,-pie -o matrix.out
```

Comment: Thanks alot Frank for your help. Could you please let me know what path I need to provide for [additional library locations and additional include] placeholder location. I am using clang2.8 and llvm2.8 version build using source code. When I tried following command  "clang matrix.s -L -mllvm -Wall -g -L. -Wl,-pie -I. -I -o matrix.out" i am getting error as clang: error: no such file or directory: 'matrix.out'
Please let me where I need to correct the command

Comment: @BalasahebDabhade, see my edit and if this answers the questions please accept. If you are no using other libraries or includes you can remove those arguments.